# grep limit output number with context

Tags: command-line, grep

If I want to find a line in file and display the surrounding context I use `grep -C`.

If I also want to limit output to the first few occurrences I add `-m` parameter

The problem is that `grep` just stops reading the file after last occurrence, not displaying the context after that line, e.g.

```
grep -C 1 -m 2 -n "string" filename
```

would display:

```
123:line before
124:string - first time
125:line after
--
--
789:line before
790:string - second time
```

line `791` will not be displayed. This is probably the right behaviour (stop reading immediately after search is done), but how can I display full context anyway?

Comment: Add Ubuntu and grep version.

Comment: It could be that line 790 is the last line in the file. What does `wc -l filename` display?

Comment: Your output looks strange. There shouldn't be two consecutive `--` there. Please show us i) your grep version; ii) a minimal input file that reproduces the problem. What is the string you are looking for? Any special characters? Are you piping the output through something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a bug to me. I'm not experiencing the same problem as you with grep version 2.16.

Assuming it's a bug with your version of grep, perhaps a workaround would be to use -B and -A instead of -C:

> grep -A 1 -B 1 -m 2 -n "string" filename